# Can SEO students ask questions on Pro Webmasters?

Tags: discussion, seo

I'm looking for a place to send my 240+ SEO students to learn and ask questions?

Will Pro Webmasters help them?

Comment: Thanks for asking this here first. As John indicated, everyone is welcome to participate provided they're aware of the guidelines for the site. The only caveat is homework questions - the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) on Stack Exchange's Meta site refers to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) about those. It might be a good idea to review that. The main issue is that this is a reference site, so questions should be helpful for others in the future...

Comment: As such, they should be about [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Theoretical and discussion-based questions (which homework questions can take the form of), aren't really a good fit for this site's single Q & A format, which is designed to answer questions factually and succinctly, with the "best" one receiving the most votes by the community and/or accepted by the OP (original poster).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. SEO is an on-topic subject here and is, in fact, [the most popular topic here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags).

But keep in mind that all questions, even from students, must follow the site's [rules](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help). As SEO questions are frequently asked, this means most questions already have an answer. I recommend that you encourage your students to use the search functionality of this site *before* asking a question as most questions will already have been answered.

I also recommend you have them take the [tour](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour) so they have a good understanding of how the site works.

Comment: Thank John I will.

Answer (score 4):

Your students are welcome to ask on-topic questions here.   Our community will do our best to support them.

I'd ask that you try not to overwhelm the site. Please don't ask all your students to post questions on the same day (or even in the same week).  This site typically only gets a few hundred questions each month. Our community has the capacity to answer more than that, but if too many questions get asked too quickly, many of them are likely to go unanswered.

Comment: Thanx Stephen. 
Sure  Students Will Read Rules And I will make sure. 
Thay Do not Post All Questions On The Same Day.